# How to get min and max from .csv column

Tags: java

I try to get min and max value from a .csv file, but my code throws me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0
>       at PSAnalyserGui.Test.main(Test.java:53)

Code:

```
public class Test {

 public static class ColMapper extends
   Mapper<Object, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {
  public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   String[] cols = value.toString().split(",");
   for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) { 
    context.write(new Text(String.valueOf(i + 1)),new 
DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(cols[i])));
   }
  }
 }
 public static class ColReducer extends
   Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> {
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values,
    Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   double min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = 0;
   Iterator<DoubleWritable> iterator = values.iterator(); //Iterating 
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    double value = iterator.next().get();
    if (value < min) { 
     min = value;
    }
    if (value > max) {
     max = value;
    }
   }
   context.write(new Text(key), new DoubleWritable(min));
   context.write(new Text(key), new DoubleWritable(max));
  }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  Job job = new Job(conf, "\\ok.csv");
  job.setJarByClass(Test.class);
  FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
  if (fs.exists(new Path(args[1]))) {
   fs.delete(new Path(args[1]), true);
  }
  job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

  job.setMapperClass(ColMapper.class);
  job.setReducerClass(ColReducer.class);

  job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
  job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
  System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
}
```

Comment: You didn't pass any command line parameters, did you?  Your code expects two, but doesn't see if there are two before attempting to use them.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is telling you that you're trying to access an element in an array that is greater than the array's dimension.

For example, given

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("index: " + i + "; value: " + arr[i]);
}
```

Will output

```
index: 0; value: 1
index: 1; value: 2
index: 2; value: 3
```

If you try to access `arr[3]` an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown.

Look through your code for these occurrences (which `args` are used when invoking the `main` method?)